# How to target an element inside a nested template literal with AddEventListener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-literals

I have the following array of objects e.g.

```
const posts = [
  {
    "year": "2021",
    "results": [
      {
        "permalink": "#",        
        "title": "15 Types Of Blog Post Titles That Get Clicked",
        "objectID": "e834b4c2819215d5da55fee02702ab51",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "2020",
    "results": [
      {
        "permalink": "#",        
        "title": "8 Types of Headlines That Get Clicked",        
        "objectID": "5f944e284e1c37db17b862f537db5387",
      },
      {
        "permalink": "#",
        "title": "7 Ways Javascript Can Haunt You",
        "objectID": "8d3200b586ca27a3513d7d1b664c5b64",
      },
      {
        "permalink": "#",        
        "title": "20 New Dark Themes for 2020",        
        "objectID": "4d95db97cd03f17e8eb92a6cee65c7a1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "2017",
    "results": [
      {
        "permalink": "#",
        "title": "Top 15 Websites to Learn Javascript",
        "objectID": "86cce2025f633287a200699f11bcd230",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Used by this template literal:

```
document.querySelector('#page').innerHTML = `
<div>
    ${posts.map(item => `
    <h3>${item.year}<h3>
        ${item.results.map(post => `
            <a id="post-link" data-post-id="${post.objectID}" href="${post.permalink}">
                <h6>${post.title}</h6>
            </a>
        `).join('')}
    `).join('')}
</div>
`
```

I'm trying to add an `AddEventListener` to the link in the second `.map`. How would I target those links?

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.matches('#post-link')) {
      const objectID = event.target.getAttribute('data-post-id');
      alert(objectID);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gwk86heb/)

I've read about [Javascript bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) but am not sure how to apply it in this case (if at all it applies).

Also appreciate any advice/comments on how I could code this better.

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs. Use `class="post-link"` instead of `id="post-link"`, and change the selector to `.post-link`

Comment: I think you have it inside out.  Instead of adding the listener to every `div` and checking its target, could you iterate over every target and only create the listener when needed?  if i'm misunderstanding, then you could also just do `event.target.addEventListener("whatever", doSomething)`

Comment: Technically, yes, that's true, but in this case that would work.

Comment: @Barmar totally missed the duplicate IDs. Thanks, will change that.